Using vbs to order all open windows in Outlook after sleep mode
In Outlook, I have many windows open simultaneously. The inbox and calendar followed by 10-15 emails with ongoing cases. When the PC has been in sleep mode and wakes up again, it has switched the order of the windows. Is it possible to write a VBA code that arranges all windows again? First Inbox, then Calendar, and then all other windows in date order. So that when hovering over the Outlook icon on the taskbar, they appear in this order?"
